# Using HTML5 Drag and Drop with Aurelia

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, aurelia

I want to implement a simple drag and drop in Aurelia but cannot seem to get the drop event to fire.

```
<template>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div draggable="true" dragstart.delegate="dragStart($event)">Drag Me</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="upload-drop-zone" dragenter.delegate="dragEnter($event)" drop.delegate="dragDrop($event)">Drop Area</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
export class DemoPage {
 dragStart(event) {
    console.log('dragstart', event);
    return true;
}

dragEnter(event) {
    console.log('dragEnter', event);
    return true;
 }

 dragDrop(event) {
    console.log('dragDrop', event);
    return true;
 }
}
```

Any help appreciated - thanks.
Matt

Comment: `drop.trigger`?

Comment: HTML5 drag and drop tends to be flaky. Try using something like aurelia-interactjs: https://github.com/eriklieben/aurelia-interactjs

Answer (score 19):

### Step 1: Implement the `dragover` callback

The [HTML 5 spec requires](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API) that you `preventDefault` on the `dragover` event in order to flag the element as being droppable. The `dragenter` callback is different. It is fired when a dragged element first enters the target element, and it is best for toggling a visual que on.

**app.html**

```
<div class="upload-drop-zone" dragover.trigger="dragOver($event)" drop.trigger="dragDrop($event)">
  Drop Area
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
dragDrop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

### Step 2: Use `trigger` over `delegate`

`delegate` is a special tool for using the [event delegation pattern](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate), an optimization. It attaches the event handler on the document body, and allows the event to propagate only on the correct elements. Since the drag and drop spec is a somewhat fragile, I recommend using `trigger` instead, which will attach the event handlers directly to the element.

**app.html**

```
<div class="row">
  <div draggable="true" dragstart.trigger="dragStart($event)">
    Drag Me
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="upload-drop-zone" dragover.trigger="dragOver($event)" drop.trigger="dragDrop($event)">
    Drop Area
  </div>
</div>
```

### Step 3 (Complete): Return `true` from event handlers

Returning `true` tells Aurelia to propagate the event to the browser. Since we're trusting the browser to do all of our dragging and dropping for us, we need to return `true` from all of our drag and drop events other than `dragover` and `drop`. See here: https://github.com/aurelia/binding/issues/336

Working Gist here: https://gist.run/?id=375dbed8d63cff44075e5f93403dd9dc

Comment: Ups if you liked it, checks if you loved it.

Comment: Extra style points for the Final Fantasy characters 